# Tentando programar puzzle a mudança de elementos em posições equivalentes de dois arrays da erro

Tags: python, array, array-multidimensional, índices, pygame

Eu estou tentando fazer um puzzle em que a imagem vem embaralhada em pedaços, e ao clicar em dois pedaços diferentes eles trocam de posição, caso o desenho esteja correto vai para o próximo.

Porem o problema é quando eu checo se o puzzle foi resolvido, a solução que tentei implementar foi criar uma lista que contivesse identificadores dos `sprites` em seus respectivos lugares caso a imagem já tivesse remontada `listaSolucao` e uma com as posições atuais dos identificadores dos `sprites` `matrizResDesenho`, então quando eu troco dois `sprites` de lugar na lista `desenho` os seus respectivos identificadores também trocam de lugar na lista `matrizResDesenho` ao final se estiver correto ambas listas serão idênticas e sairá do loop.

A principio funciona porem depois de algumas trocas de `sprites` os identificadores começam a trocar aleatoriamente entre si ou então simplesmente não mudam, visualmente funciona perfeitamente, mas por conta desse erro a lista `matrizResDesenho` não cumpre sua função em ser comparada com a solução, ainda que o desenho esteja certo na tela.

Gostaria de saber onde esta meu erro no seguinte código, e se há outro método melhor para conseguir fazer isso que eu quero.

Tentei comparar `sprites` mas sempre retorna falso então não é um método viável.

Agradeço a quem ler tudo e me ajudar.

````
    while(puzzleAtivo):
        deltaClique += deltatime 

        for x in range(4):
            for y in range(4):
                if (mouse.is_over_object(desenho[x][y])): # se o mouse estiver em cima da imagem

                    if (mouse.is_button_pressed(1) and deltaClique > 1): # se o mouse clicar na imagem
                        deltaClique = 0 # limite de tempo para clicar novamente

                        if(segurando): # checa se há um sprite sendo "segurado"

                            atualX, atualY = desenho[x][y].x, desenho[x][y].y #armazena as posicoes atuais do sprite


                            # inverte as posições dos sprites em si na tela
                            desenho[x][y].x = desenho[seguradoX][seguradoY].x 
                            desenho[x][y].y = desenho[seguradoX][seguradoY].y

                            desenho[seguradoX][seguradoY].x = atualX
                            desenho[seguradoX][seguradoY].y = atualY

                            auxRes = matrizResDesenho[seguradoX][seguradoY] #armazena o index do identificador do sprite que ja estava sendo "segurado"

                            # inverte os identificadores do sprite que acaba de ser clicado com o que ja estava sendo "segurado"
                            matrizResDesenho[seguradoX][seguradoY] = matrizResDesenho[x][y]

                            matrizResDesenho[x][y] = auxRes

                            segurando = False

                        else:

                            seguradoX , seguradoY = x,y #se ao clicar em uma imagem ainda nao houver sprite sendo segurado armazena o index desta que acaba de ser clicada
                            segurando = True



        if checaSolucao(solucao, matrizResDesenho):
            break ```
````